# Verificar no URL se tem uma variavel passada GET LUA

Tags: lua

Quero verificar através do URL se tenho alguma variável passada para via `GET`. 
Por exemplo neste url: `www.exemplo.htm?teste=teste`

```
if url then -- se na barra de endereço tem um get
  return true
 else
  return false
 end
```

Tenho uma variável passada, como posso verificar isso em linguagem `LUA`?

Comment: Supondo a URL: `www.exemplo.htm?chave1=valor1&chave2=valor2`, você quer saber se o `valor1` está presente nela?

Comment: Sim isso mesmo, quero saber se o url tem algum parametro passado. Se sim retornar true e se não tiver nada, ou seja o url ser apenas www.exemplo.htm retornar false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma maneira de fazer isto é usar a [função `string.gmatch`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/pt/manual.html#pdf-string.gmatch):

```
function checkURL(url, parametro)
    for chave, valor in string.gmatch(url, "(%w+)=(%w+)") do
        if valor == parametro then
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end
```

Utilize a função `checkURL` assim:

```
if checkURL("www.exemplo.htm?chave1=valor1&chave2=valor2", "valor1") then
    print ("valor1 está presente na URL")
else
    print ("valor1 NÃO foi encontrado na URL")
end
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/Bj4fil)

Uma outra alternativa é usar a [função `string.find`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/pt/manual.html#pdf-string.find):

```
url = "www.exemplo.htm?chave1=valor1&chave2=valor2"

if string.find(url, "valor1") then
    print ("valor1 está presente na URL")
else
    print ("valor1 NÃO foi encontrado na URL")
end
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/2GVpbt)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas isso eu tenho de passar o url por paramentro na função. Não ha maneira de ir "buscar" automaticamente?

Comment: @akm Atualizei a resposta, veja se é isso.

Comment: certo mas o url continua a ser uma variavel, queria que fosse buscar directamente da barra de endereços do browser. E depois sim passar pela condição.

Comment: @akm Ai vai depender de como você implementa isto, você pode pegar esse endereço e colocá-lo na variável e fazer a comparação, o que você usa para fazer as requisições? [Esse](https://github.com/pintsized/lua-resty-http)?